# How to iterate through items of a menu built in laravel voyager in a blade file?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am trying to do this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($items as $menu_item)
        <li><a href="{{ $menu_item->link() }}">{{ $menu_item->title }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

as mentioned in the [docs here](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/core-concepts/menus-and-menu-builder). But I am unable to figure out how to assign the menuitems from `menu('admin')` to `$items`.

The docs are unclear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@php
    $items =  menu('frontpage_menu','_json');
@endphp

<nav class="primary-menu">
    <ul class="menu-container">
        @foreach($items as $menu_item)
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="{{ $menu_item->link()}}" class="menu-link">{{ $menu_item->title }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```